# jquery: modifing attributes of a clone

Tags: jquery

I have a slice of html that looks like this:

```
<div class="search_container">
    <input id="keywords_0_keyword_names" name="keywords[0][keyword_names]" type="text">
    <select id="keywords_0_keyword_conditions" name="keywords[0][keyword_conditions]">
        <option value="is">is</option>
        <option value="is not">is not</option>
        <option value="is like">is like</option>
    </select>
    <input id="keywords_0_keyword_values" name="keywords[0][keyword_values]" type="text">
</div>
```

I want to clone that and then modify the id and name attributes to hold 1 not 0:

```
var next_index = 1;
var $container = $(".search_container");
var $new_container = $container.clone();
$new_container.find( $( "input[id^='keywords_'],select[id^='keywords_']" ) ).each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id").replace(/\d/,next_index);
    $(this).attr("name").replace(/\d/,next_index);
})
$container.parent().append($new_container); // form-group div which stores all the search containers
```

The problem is it seems that the id and name attributes of clone are not permanently changed, because when I load web page, the cloned html still holds a value of 0 and not 1.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, you cloned it, and changed the clone's attribute, but where is the clone placed on the page? It doesn't seem like it's appended/prepended anywhere.

Comment: @cYn I thought that part could go without say. It does successfully add the clone to the page, because I can see a second .search_container on the page, but the value is still 0 and not 1.

Comment: Sorry, had to get the simple stuff out of the way first. Also, your .find() selector is incorrect. The code never enters the .find().each() statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

When using `.find()`, you should not include the jQuery wrapper on the selector. Use `.find("input[id^='keywords_'],select[id^='keywords_']")` instead.

You also need to apply the new attributes to the elements, since replace returns a string.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tky1dbua/1/)

```
var next_index = 1;
var $container = $(".search_container");
var $new_container = $container.clone();
$new_container.find("input[id^='keywords_'],select[id^='keywords_']")
              .each(function(){
    // Get new attributes
    var new_id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/\d/,next_index);
    var new_name = $(this).attr("name").replace(/\d/,next_index);
    // Apply new attributes
    $(this).attr('id',new_id);
    $(this).attr('name',new_name);
})
$container.parent().append($new_container);
```